# how to get the international string in flutter

Tags: flutter, internationalization

In the flutter, I store a global locale in the getx `get: 4.6.5` global controller. Then change the local in global controller and force to refresh the applicaiton. I am using this code to get the international string in flutter componnet:

```
      String home = Intl.message('nav_home');
```

I have already define he `Intl_en.arb` and `Intl_zh.arb` like this:

```
{
  "@@last_modified": "2018-12-10T15:46:20.897228",
  "@@locale":"en",
  "title": "Flutter App",
  "@title": {
    "description": "Title for the Demo application",
    "type": "text",
    "placeholders": {}
  },
  "@nav_home":{
        "description": "Home",
      "type": "text",
      "placeholders": {}
  }
}
```

but the Intl `intl: ^0.17.0` message always get the en words every time. Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? BTW, this is the global define of Locale look like:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:wheel/wheel.dart';

import '../page/nav/nav.dart';
import '../page/settings/setting/setting_controller.dart';
import 'global_controller.dart';

class AppPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentTheme = ThemeManager.fromThemeName("lightTheme");
    Get.put(SettingController());
    final settingController = Get.find<SettingController>();

    Widget buildHomePage() {
      return new Nav();
    }

    return GetBuilder<GlobalController>(
        init: GlobalController(),
        builder: (controller) {
          return GetMaterialApp(
            title: 'SleepEase',
            theme: currentTheme,
            navigatorKey: NavigationService.instance.navigationKey,
            checkerboardOffscreenLayers: controller.showDebug,
            checkerboardRasterCacheImages: controller.showDebug,
            showPerformanceOverlay: controller.showDebug,
            localizationsDelegates: [
              GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate
            ],
            locale: settingController.appLocale,
            supportedLocales: [
              const Locale('en', 'US'),
              const Locale('zh', 'CN'),
            ],
            routes: {

            },
            home: buildHomePage(),
            onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {},
          );
        });
  }
}
```

this is how to change the Locale setting in global setting controller:

```
void updateLocale(Locale newLocale){
    appLocale = newLocale;
    Get.forceAppUpdate();
  }
```

I am sure the app refreshed after update the global locale setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this way I have better suggestion for you:
You could leave it to Getx to do it for you !:)

so simple with few steps

#### Step 1

create class and extend it from `Translations`:

```dart
  class Messages extends Translations {
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
        'en_US': {
          'hello': 'Hello',
        },
        'fa_IR': {
          'hello': 'سلام',
        },
        // add more translations here
      };
}
```

This class contains methods which returns map .
the key of map is the country locale and then the value of
that would be again a map which all translations go there
all locale maps should have shared key for doing translation
but the value of them is the value in that locale.
if you look close enough you would notice that `hello` is shared between locales but the `values` are different.
after that you add your all Strings  it time to move next step

#### Step 2

after declaring your translations up there you should put your  locales in `GetMaterialApp` like this.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return GetMaterialApp(
     translations: Messages(), // your translations
     locale: Locale('fa', 'IR'), // default locale
// this use when app couldn't translate and its name suggest made locale this
     fallbackLocale: Locale('en', 'US'),
     home: HomePage(),
   );
 }
}
```

now after so far its time for last step which you are going to use

#### Step 3

here you should use your key which you had define up there which is shared between all locales for exam that `hello`
like this
Text('hello'.tr)
this `.tr` would make your String translatable to locales of app.
hope that help you
if you confused you could email me and we would talk more
my mail => abolfazlmsahhadi93@gmai.com
or you could use this link
https://www.fun4code.com/flutter-translations-with-getx/

Comment: thank you, this is clean and simeple to use, I think it's better than Intl. @Abolfazl Mashhadi

Comment: It's my pleasure, when ever you need help feel free to email me